# How to bypass a not nullable property when displaying a model in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

So I have this property in my model :

```
public string ImageBase64 => System.Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData);
```

I cannot make it nullable by addding a `?` in after the `string` part, because i get :

> the type string must be a nonnullable type in order to use it as a parameter  in the generic type or method Nullable

In my view I tried with the following condition, which worked(or didn't work) the same, and I stil got the `Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: inArray`  on F5:

```
@if (Model.ImageBase64 != null)
{
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImageData)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Model.ImageBase64" />

        </dd>
    }
```

This is my  action method :

```
public ActionResult UserProfile()
    {

        //
        string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        //ApplicationUser currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
        UserDetails userDetails = db.UsersDetails.Where(c => c.identtyUserId == currentUserId)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);
        //
       // var usersDetails = db.UsersDetails.Include(u => u.Company);
        return View(userDetails);
    }
```

Any ideas how can I just ignore the property if it is null and still display the rest of the propertirs, that aren't?

Comment: It's not clear to me what's actually throwing that error, but if you need to check for null *or* empty strings you can use: `@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ImageBase64))`

Answer (score 1):

That error you are getting is an indication of your ImageData either being null or ill formatted. I believe it's the System.Convert.ToBase64 method that is failing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx

Additionally, you can't add ? to the string type because it already can be nullable (basically what that compile message you got says).

Where is ImageData coming from? Is it a byte array?

Edited to include answer after questions:

```
public string ImageBase64
{
    get
    {

        return this.ImageData != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(this.ImageData) : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is a byt array. I cannot add ?. I said why in the question.

Comment: Is the byte array null though? Simply don't do the conversion if it's null. Then you'll be able to check ImageBase64 for null itself without an error.

Comment: Yes, the byte array is empty. Would it be possible to demonstrate what you mean in an answer. I am a novice and not sure what to do from what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
    public string ImageBase64 => ( imagedata == null )?
String.Empty:System.Convert.ToBase64String(imagedata);
```